# How to add additional column to an output recordset from another data source in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I have a Data Flow in an SSIS Package that gets data from an SQL server using an OLE DB source (call it *`source1`*). I am saving that data to my final destination database with a OLE DB Destination. Our users have asked for a new requirement, between the source and final destination to pick up  a piece of data from another source database (call it *`source2`*)  based on a column value key picked up from *`source1`*. Then with the combined data of *`source1`* and *`source2`* save it to the destination place. Is there a way to do that in SSIS ? The only thing i can think of it to get all the possible data from source 2 and save it into a temp table in the destination and then link it up. I don't want to do this since this could be a lot of data!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your needs, you are looking for a [Lookup Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141821.aspx). To get the best performance, you will want to use a query and only retrieve the columns you need to make the match + the columns you need to add to your output.

Answer (score 0):

Use a recordset destination from Source 1 and save everything from source 1 in that. In another DFT, you can read from Source 2 and then combine both 1 and 2 to dump into the destination. Hope this helps.

Comment: How would you use a Recordset Destination as a source for a data flow? I'm only familiar with shredding them with a Foreach Loop Container.

Comment: Mixing my thoughts. I did something similar, but forgot that I ultimately used a lookup transformation to use that recordset. My bad.

Comment: No worries, went bingling and found people using a script task to accomplish. Downside though being you must define your own metadata.